# If we call autorelease on object , How and why it crashes at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I thought, if we call autorelease on object, it decrements retain count and when finally pool drains it clears the object from autorelease pool. But how it crashes at run time when autorelease is called on object. Can anyone explain with example.

Comment: Can you show your code?  Why aren’t you using ARC?

Comment: autorelease does not decrement retain count. it puts the object into an autorelease pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under MRR/MRC the programmer is responsible for retaining and releasing objects. If there are more retains than releases then an object stays alive, when the number of releases matches the number of retains then the object is freed, and if after that a further release is performed then a crash may occur.

An autorelease is just a delayed release, so it can cause a crash just like a release can. E.g. sample timeline:

> Create/retain object
>
> Use object
>
> Autorelease object - object stored in pool for later release
>
> Keep using object - fine as it's still alive
>
> Release object - object is freed, occupied memory can be reused
>
> ...
>
> Pool is emptied, object pointer now referencing long dead object is passed to release... boom.

This is just one scenario, there are others, e.g. Autoreleasing an object too many (more than it's been retained) times.

That's the *how*. To fix it either carefully review your manual memory management or go automatic and switch to ARC and just deal with manually avoiding leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking manual retain count issues can be done by the „Static Analyzer“ in Xcode. It explains why and where your memory issues occour. Run it and fix your issues.